# Use host's jsonArray values in android

Tags: php, android, sql, json, listview

I need to send values of jsonArray to my android code in order to populate a listView.
This is my `rankingsReader.php` file:

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName";
$dbUsername = "dbUsername";
$dbPassword = "dbPassword";
$dbName = "dbName";
$tableName = "tableName";

$conn = new mysqli($serverName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

try{
    $sqlTopMembers = "SELECT XP, username FROM $tableName ORDER BY XP DESC LIMIT 10";
    if (!($result = $conn->query($sqlTopMembers)))
        die($conn->error);
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        $rankings = [];
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rankings[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode(array($tableName => $rankings));
    }
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Error ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is the format of my jsonArray:

```
{"androidlogin":[{"XP":"24","username":"amin39"},{"XP":"24","username":"amin21"},{"XP":"3","username":"amin222"},{"XP":"2","username":"mahdi"},{"XP":"0","username":"amin49"},{"XP":"0","username":"amin20"},{"XP":"0","username":"amin22"},{"XP":"0","username":"Leopard"},{"XP":"0","username":"kjjkjhh"},{"XP":"0","username":"dashagh"}]}
```

And I want to fill my listView(`rankings_list`) in android.
This is my `RankingListActivity.java` class:

```
public class RankingListActivity extends MainPage {
private static final String link = "http://myapp.webhost.com/rankingsReader.php";
Connection rankingConnect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_ranking_list, (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flContent));

    ListView rankingsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rankings_list);
    setRanking();

}
private void setRanking() {
    rankingConnect = new Connection(){
        @Override
        protected ProgressDialog createNewDialog(ProgressDialog dialog) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(RankingListActivity.this);
            return dialog;
        }

        @Override
        protected String setUrl() {
            return link;
        }
    };
}}
```

I have read some about `Uri.Builder` and `json`, but I don't know how to use it in my android code. please help me to fill my listView(`rankings_list`) by values of jsonArray.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model

Ranking List Array Model

```
public class RankingList {
    ArrayList<RankingList> androidLogin;
    public ArrayList<RankingList> getAndroidLogin() {
        return androidLogin;
    }

    public void setAndroidLogin(ArrayList<RankingList> androidLogin) {
        this.androidLogin = androidLogin;
    }
}
```

Ranking List Model

```
public class RankingList {
    String XP;
    String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
       this.username = username;
    }

    public String getXP() {
        return XP;
    }

    public void setXP(String XP) {
        this.XP = XP;
    }

}
```

Create a getter and setter and then use this to fill the data from Gson.toJson();

```
Gson.toJson(your_string, RankingListArray.class);
```

This will do the Job